# Use value in column to name .csv file

Tags: r

I am using `write.csv()` in R to create many csv files from dataframes. I am currently manually naming the csv file each time. Is there a way to use the values in specific columns in the dataframe to name the file in `write.csv()`?

For example, here is a part of the dataframe:

| Date | Time | Camera |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-13 | 05_26_15 | 1 |
| 2022-06-13 | 06_26_20 | 1 |
| 2022-06-13 | 07_26_20 | 1 |
| 2022-06-13 | 08_26_21 | 1 |

I want to name the file with the value for the "Date" column and the "Camera" column. Something like this:

```
write.csv(df, "Camera_01_2022_06_13.csv")
```

I've tried using some of the same syntax as I use to read in files with specific names (via pattern = ) but haven't had any luck.

Thanks for any tips!

Edit: Here is what the data frame actually looks like.

```
    df <- structure(list(SourceFile = c("C:/Users/Jen/Desktop/CameraTrap_Organized/Site_01/TIMEL0012/TL_Directory/05_26_21.jpg", 
"C:/Users/Jen/Desktop/CameraTrap_Organized/Site_01/TIMEL0012/TL_Directory/06_26_20.jpg", 
"C:/Users/Jen/Desktop/CameraTrap_Organized/Site_01/TIMEL0012/TL_Directory/07_26_21.jpg", 
"C:/Users/Jen/Desktop/CameraTrap_Organized/Site_01/TIMEL0012/TL_Directory/08_26_20.jpg", 
"C:/Users/Jen/Desktop/CameraTrap_Organized/Site_01/TIMEL0012/TL_Directory/09_26_21.jpg", 
"C:/Users/Jen/Desktop/CameraTrap_Organized/Site_01/TIMEL0012/TL_Directory/10_26_20.jpg"
), NewfileName = c("05_26_21.jpg", "06_26_20.jpg", "07_26_21.jpg", 
"08_26_20.jpg", "09_26_21.jpg", "10_26_20.jpg"), Species = c("Bird", 
"None", "Cpic", "None", "Cpic", "None"), Count = c("0", "0", 
"1", "0", "1", "0"), X.1 = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 50L), format = c("JPEG", 
"JPEG", "JPEG", "JPEG", "JPEG", "JPEG"), width = c(2688L, 2688L, 
2688L, 2688L, 2688L, 2688L), height = c(1512L, 1512L, 1512L, 
1512L, 1512L, 1512L), colorspace = c("sRGB", "sRGB", "sRGB", 
"sRGB", "sRGB", "sRGB"), matte = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), filesize = c(211274L, 340107L, 338587L, 247198L, 
234634L, 201246L), density = c("72x72", "72x72", "72x72", "72x72", 
"72x72", "72x72"), fileName = c("images-0001.jpg", "images-0003.jpg", 
"images-0004.jpg", "images-0005.jpg", "images-0009.jpg", "images-0050.jpg"
), row_id = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 50L), X = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
9L, 50L), Date = c("6/14/2022", "6/14/2022", "6/14/2022", "6/14/2022", 
"6/14/2022", "6/14/2022"), Time = c("05_26_21", "06_26_20", "07_26_21", 
"08_26_20", "09_26_21", "10_26_20"), Camera = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("exiftoolr", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Do you mean save the whole data.frame based its first column values ? or partition based on Date camera columns ?

Comment: You should be able to use `paste()` for this, but you need to provide reproducible data since the date values can be stored in multiple ways and that will affect the answer. Use `dput(head(dataname))` and paste the results into your question.

Comment: @MohamedDesouky - yes, save whole data.frame based on column values in first row (these values are the same throughout the column).

Comment: @dcarlson thanks for the tips on how to share reproducible data. This is my first Q on stack, still learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste` the different parts together including a column name. I add a second `paste0` statement in order to add the `.csv` to the end of the filename. We can use `sprintf` to add a leading 0.

```
write.csv(df, paste0(paste(
  names(df[3]), sprintf("%02d", df$Camera[1]), gsub("[-]", "_", df$Date[1]), sep = "_"
), ".csv"))

# [1] "Camera_01_2022_06_13.csv"
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2022-06-13", "2022-06-13", "2022-06-13", 
"2022-06-13"), Time = c("05_26_15", "06_26_20", "07_26_20", "08_26_21"
), Camera = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: thanks! This worked! I just had to adjust as follows for the df included in my edit to the original post. 

write.csv(df_timelapse, paste0(paste(
  names(df_timelapse[18]), sprintf("%02d", df_timelapse$Camera[1]), 
  gsub("[/]", "_", df_timelapse$Date[1]), sep = "_"), ".csv"))

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, and fine tune to your own needs:

```r
library(stringr)

df <- structure(list(Date = c("2022-06-13", "2022-06-13", "2022-06-13"
), Time = c("05_26_15", "06_26_20", "07_26_20"), Camera = c(1L, 
1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

file_name <- str_c("Camera", df$Camera[1], df$Date[1], sep = "_") %>%
  str_replace_all("[:punct:]", "_") %>%
  str_c(".csv")

#"Camera_1_2022_06_13.csv"
```